# Permanent error after import IOkit framework

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4, import, iokit

i'm new in this forum.
I'm trying to work with light sensor in iphone but the only framework that permits it is IOKit.
i tried to add the framework follow this guide:

http://ios-blog.co.uk/tutorials/iokit-an-introduction/

but xcode returns me some error.

Error's List: http://pastebin.com/TMimhsXF

i linked the framework in Build Phases and after this i downloaded the header and put in search path(/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.6.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/IOKit.framework) the path .

Now afterward i put the framework ( path of framework)in the framework folder. But when i compiled it xcode returned this error and if i try to remove that framework the problem persist.
how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific which error does occur?